# Anaconda: Permanently include external packages (like in PYTHONPATH)

Tags: python, anaconda, pythonpath

I know how to install packages in Anaconda using `conda install` and also how to install packages that are on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) which is described in the [manual](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs.html).

But how can I permanently include packages/folders into the `PYTHONPATH` of an Anaconda environment so that code that I am currently working on can be imported and is still available after a reboot?

My current approach is to use `sys`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/path/to/my/package')
```

which is not really convenient.

Any hints?

Comment: I don't understand what *"permanently include packages/folders in Anaconda e.g. with code that I am currently working on"* means, do you mean a) `conda and pip` are not locally installing them into the right conda environment (in which case do `conda activate/deactivate` until you get to the right Python environment, you may have several in conda), or b) you want to manually bundle third-party packages with your package(? sounds like a terrible idea, just define package dependencies). What does "permanently" mean, on which machine?

Comment: I just want to be code that I am working on to be available/importable within a specific environment even after reboot. So I have specified the question above. Actually, I found different solutions for my problem which I have provided below. But let me know if there are others ways and I'll add them!

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I found two answers to my question in the [Anaconda forum](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/RO_h0wD7sKE):

1.) Put the modules into into site-packages, i.e. the directory `$HOME/path/to/anaconda/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` which is always on `sys.path`. This should also work by creating a symbolic link.

2.) Add a `.pth` file to the directory `$HOME/path/to/anaconda/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`. This can be named anything (it just must end with `.pth`). A `.pth` file is just a newline-separated listing of the full path-names of directories that will be added to your path on Python startup.

**Alternatively**, if you only want to link to a particular conda environment then add the .pth file to `~/anaconda3/envs/{NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT}/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/`

Both work straightforward and I went for the second option as it is more flexible.

*** UPDATE:

3.) Use [conda develop](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-develop.html) i. e. `conda-develop /path/to/module/` to add the module which creates a `.pth` file as described under option 2.).

4.) Create a [setup.py](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) in the folder of your package and install it using `pip install -e /path/to/package` which is the cleanest option from my point of view because you can also see all installations using `pip list`. Note that the option `-e` allows to edit the package code. See [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) for more information.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Still waiting for [`conda develop`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/build/conda-develop.html) :/

Comment: [`conda develop`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/build/conda-develop.html), basically a script that achieves option 2, seems to be functional now.

Comment: #2 doesn't seem to work for me (I don't seem to have the same directory structure as well; I don't have multiple options for python.X.X and my 'lib' is upper case)

Comment: @information_interchange  Quite plausibly the cause for these differences in directory structure are caused by `Windows vs. Linux` implementation.  Under Windows, the places where python looks as it builds `sys.path` are slightly different.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html    I believe the path in Windows would be `....path_to_anaconda/lib/site-packages`  (also the upper/lowercase would be irrelevant in Windows)

Comment: I wonder what happen with the pip install option if I change the code afterwards. Need the package to be reinstalled? Can this solution give problems? pythonpath mechanism was an easy way to include code under development, I cannot say what is the best alternative.

Comment: If you install it as "editable mode" via `pip install -e package_name` you can change the code within package directly. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs

Comment: Option 4 worked for me. It is much easier to add to your path from linux, but if you are stuck on Windows, this is a good solution.

Comment: FWIW, I haven't  been able to get the `conda develop` approach to work. According to [this link](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/1992) it doesn't seem like it really works at this point.

Comment: `conda develop` can accept multiple path at once, so if your path contais spaces and you pass it to `conda develop` without enclosing it in quotes, several lines (with wrong paths) are added to the .pth file. If you pass it enclosed in quotes, a single line is added to .pth, but of course it contains spaces, I didn't understand yet if this works with anaconda or not (it doesn't for me, but I am sure in my case there are other problems).

Comment: make sure you run `conda install conda-build` first

Comment: When I add `my.pth` file to `/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/`, the path shows up in the base environment, but it doesn't show up in another environment. Is this intended or am I missing something?

Answer (score 13):

I'm able to include local modules using the following:

```
conda-develop /path/to/module/
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have adapted my answer as the command only creates a `.pth` file as described under 2.).

Comment: **Tip** (got hung up on this):  /path/to/module shouldn't include the module name.; just the parent directory's path.

Comment: Note: If there is some element of the package that has to be compiled, such as a Cython or f2py code, you can use: python setup.py build_ext --inplace

Comment: @ArielWerle, can you delete the path in sys.path permanently (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011104/how-to-delete-a-certain-path-in-sys-path-in-anaconda-env-base) ?

Comment: "'conda-develop' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Answer (score 4):

The way I do this, which I believe is the most native to `conda`, is by creating `env_vars.sh` files in my environment, as per the official documentation [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables).

For macOS and Linux users, the steps are as follows:

1. Go to your environment folder (e.g. `/miniconda1/env/env_name`). `$CONDA_PREFIX` is the environemnt variable for your environment path.

   ```
   cd $CONDA_PREFIX
   ```
2. Create the `activate.d` and `deactivate.d` directories.

   ```
   mkdir -p ./etc/conda/activate.d
   mkdir -p ./etc/conda/deactivate.d
   ```
3. Inside the each respective directory, create one `env_vars.sh` file. The one in the `activate.d` directory will set (or `export`) your environment variables when you `conda activate` your environment. The file in the `deactivate.d` directory will serve to unset the environment variables when you `conda deactivate` your environment.

   ```
   touch ./etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
   touch ./etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh
   ```
4. First edit the `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh` to `export` the desired environment variables.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   export VAR_A='some-thing-here'
   export VAR_B=/path/to/my/file/
   ```
5. Afterwards, open to edit the `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/deactivate/env_vars.sh`, in order to `unset` the env variables when you `conda deactivate` like so:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   unset VAR_A
   unset VAR_B
   ```

Again, the source of my description comes straight from the `conda` docs [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Cord Kaldemeyer's answer above, for the 2nd option.  If you only want to link to a particular conda environment then add the .pth file to `~/anaconda3/envs/{NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT}/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/`