# Include external package in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I'd like to include an external library (developed internaly) we are using in our team in Anacoda folder. I know the simple way is to put the package directly into `C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages`.

However I need to keep the library at a different place. One of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006114/anaconda-permanently-include-external-packages-like-in-pythonpath) here suggested to create a `.pth` file in the `site-packages`, which is solution I like. Therefore I created file `name.pth` where there is one line with path of the library `C:/path to/whatever/library`. However if I restart Spyder and try to import the library, I get an error

> ImportError: No module named XXX

I am thinking that I probably specified the path in a wrong way? Also there is a blank space in the path. Maybe that could be a problem?

[Python 2.7 with Anacodna distribution 4.3.17, Windows 7]

**EDIT**

So far I found that I can create a `.py` file in the `site-packages` folder which contains following:

```
# make path
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/path to/whatever/library')

from packageA import A1, A2, A3
from packageB import B1, B2, B3
```

If I keep the same name, the import works just fine. But then everytime I add a new package or function, the `.py` file must be updated, which is really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I found a way how to fix the `.pth` solution. The problem was in the folder structure. If the `.pth` file looks like this: `C:/path to/whatever/library_name`, then the directory to the library must look as follows: `C:/path to/whatever/library_name/library_name`.

Basically instead of pointing to the files, one must point to the folder containg the files. Silly mistake.