# Anaconda: Permanently import own module, but not their "directory-wise siblings"

Tags: python, anaconda

I have multiple Python projects (which are also Git repositories) in a "GitHub" folder like so:

```
GitHub/
├── Project_1/
│   ├── main.py
│   └── ...
└── Project_2/
    ├── main.py
    └── ...
```

Now what I want is to `import Project_1` inside of a .py file of Project_2 (for example main.py).

I searched the net of course and found these related questions:

- [Anaconda: Permanently include external packages (like in PYTHONPATH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006114/anaconda-permanently-include-external-packages-like-in-pythonpath)
- [Include external package in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153181/include-external-package-in-anaconda)

However, they all describe how I would manage to `import GitHub`, which is not what I want, since I get a weird self-import of Project_2 then.

Is there any way of achieving what I want, while still keeping the possibility of modifying all the code "on the fly" (without having to install it every time again or so)?

I am using PyCharm by the way - in case there is an internal workaround.

Please also tell me if anything I am doing is bad practice, and why - so I can learn from it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the project [packages are properly, well, packaged](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), i.e. that you can in general `pip install` them, then you can also use `pip install -e` (`-e` for `--editable`) to have `pip` just link them to your current environment instead of copying files over.

That way the packages remain editable in their directories and are usable just like any other package.

## Example

An example of an easily workable tree of projects might be something like the below.

```
- my_projects/ (née GitHub)
  - project1/
    - setup.py (or pyproject.toml)
    - package1/
      - __init__.py
      - mod1.py
      - mod2.py
  - project2/
    - setup.py (or pyproject.toml)
    - package2/
      - __init__.py
      - mod3.py
      - mod4.py
  - project3/
    - secretproject/
      - __init__.py
      - __main__.py  # to allow running `python -m secretproject`
      - mod5.py
```

This assumes `project1` and `project2` are projects containing packages you'd want to use in `project3`, which doesn't necessarily need to be reusable.

If `project1` and `project2` have been properly configured for package installation (see the link above), you could then, in `project3`'s virtualenv, do `pip install -e ~/my_projects/project1 -e ~/my_projects/project2` and `package1` and `package2` are available for `secretproject` to use.

Comment: Is it "well packaged" when I have all the .py files directly on top (see directory tree)? I get this error when trying your idea: "Can't get a consistent path to setup script from installation directory". I like the approach though!

Comment: Not quite... See my edit!

Comment: Okay, now this is not my directory tree anymore ("packages are in extra folders")... If I change it to your example, I by now know a bunch of ways to achieve my goal... I was hoping there exists yet another possibility, where the .py files can be imported across Projects

Comment: There are no non-standard ways to do something like that. You could fiddle with `sys.path`, but I **very strongly** advise against it, since e.g. IDE support will break.

Comment: Yes, I understand - I now changed my directory tree and I'm gonna accept this answer