# Linking to python libraries from different python executables on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I am relatively new to Python and trying to figure out how to set up my different implementations of Python. To run different packages, I have multiple installations of python 2.7 and 3.6, both 32-bit and 64-bit. For example, I run some GIS software that uses its own implementation of python (OSGEO4W) that I run from the installation location (32-bit Python 2.7). This python executable has a package (otbApplication), that doesn't really install from pip or conda. However, I mainly run python (also 32-bit Python 2.7) from Anaconda. When I am running from Anaconda, is there a way to have otbApplication and other libraries in OSGEO4W implementation of Python available?

Comment: Try creating virtual environments and then install different versions in different virtualenv. See here for details. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: That seems like a great way to do it using pip and virtualenvs. I am looking for a way to do this in Anaconda. Can't seem to find the right way to do it, if there is a way

Comment: Yes there is way as per official docs, pls check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have anaconda up and running you can use following process to install anaconda equivalent of virtual environment.

**Make sure you are able access anaconda from your current folder**

```
(base) C:\Users>conda -V
conda 4.4.7
```

**Lookup python version available to be installed.**
long list, truncated here

```
(base) C:\Users>conda search "^python$"
Loading channels: done
Name                       Version                   Build  Channel
python                     2.6.8                         5  defaults
|
|
|
python                     3.6.4                h6538335_1  defaults
```

**Create virtual environment with selected python version**

```
(base) C:\Users>conda create -n testVirtualEnv python=3.6.4 anaconda
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Anaconda3\envs\testVirtualEnv

  added / updated specs:
    - anaconda
    - python=3.6.4
|
|

#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate testVirtualEnv
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
```

**Activate virtual environment**
Notice context changed from (base) to (testVirtualEnv)

```
(base) C:\Users>conda activate testVirtualEnv
```

**Test to check python version in virtual env.**

```
(testVirtualEnv) C:\Users>python -V
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

**Install a package in virtual env**

```
(testVirtualEnv) C:\Users>conda install -n testVirtualEnv openpyxl
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Anaconda3\envs\testVirtualEnv
  added / updated specs:
    - openpyxl   
|
|
Executing transaction: done
```

**Deactivate running environment**
Notice context changed to (base)

```
(testVirtualEnv) C:\Users>conda deactivate
(base) C:\Users>
```

**Remove and delete virtual Env**

```
(base) C:\Users>conda remove -n testVirtualEnv --all    
Remove all packages in environment C:\Anaconda3\envs\testVirtualEnv    
Proceed ([y]/n)? y    
(base) C:\Users>
```

You can research further commands at [official documentation site](https://conda.io/docs/commands.html?highlight=virtualenv).

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. Unfortunately, what I need to create a link to a specific python interpreter. In my specific case, the interpreter is located at C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/python.exe. When I create the virtual environment as you specify, it creates an interpreter at C:\Anaconda3\envs\testVirtualEnv. Does this makes sense?

Comment: You can use `-p` option to create virtualenv at specified location e.g. :  `conda create -p C:/OSGeo4W64/testVirtualEnv python=3.6.4 anaconda` , As far as interpreter goes, conda utilizes its own and not from previously installed python versions, so sourcing them may not be necessary.

Comment: This only saves the virtual environment in the location. I am still unable to import packages that are located where the OSGeo4W64/bin/python interpreter is located. The method is similar to tutorial at this link https://my.usgs.gov/confluence/display/EGIS/Using+Anaconda+modules+from+the+ESRI+python+environment. Unfortunately, it is offline right now (probably because of US Government Shutdown)

Comment: I believe you are looking to link/add existing packages to conda env. Check this link for possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006114/anaconda-permanently-include-external-packages-like-in-pythonpath and https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/09/06/a-simple-approach-for-including-3rd-party-python-libraries-with-your-scripts/