# How to install Python package when using Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have installed this python package called shuttle using git bash. It works fine when I am using it in git bash. But when I am trying to import shuttle from Spyder or even Jupyter Notebook, its showing error -

ImportError: No module named 'shuttle'

Can you please explain why I am seeing this error and how can I fix it ?

Update: What I realise from searching in google, pip install/spyder/anaconda all have different environment. Because I installed 'shuttle' using pip, Spyder doesn't know about it. So now the problem is how do I install the package in Spyder environment or how do I make Spyder recognise that 'Shuttle' is already installed ?

Comment: Use `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: Uninstalled shuttle and reinstalled using pip3. still getting same error.

Comment: If you installed Python with Anaconda, then you should use `conda` instead of `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:
1. Install the package via pip. In your case shuttle
2. Locate the directory where shuttle is installed. You can do that by opening terminal
    `python`
    `import shuttle`
    `shuttle #displays location of shuttle`
3. Now add shuttle to /path/to/anaconda/lib/

reference post: [Anaconda: Permanently include external packages (like in PYTHONPATH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006114/anaconda-permanently-include-external-packages-like-in-pythonpath)