# Jupyter notebook - can't import python functions from other folders

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook, I want to use local python functions from other folders in my computer.
When I do import to these functions I get this error:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'

- I'm using anaconda as the python interpreter

Answer (score 9):

You can add a path using `sys` to your local module/python file.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/file/")  # path contains python_file.py

import python_file
```

If you want a more permanent solution by adding module to Anaconda path, see previous answer from cord-kaldemeyer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37008663/7019148. Content copied below for completeness:

> I found two answers to my question in the Anaconda forum:
>
> 1.) Put the modules into into site-packages, i.e. the directory $HOME/path/to/anaconda/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages which is always on
>   sys.path. This should also work by creating a symbolic link.
>
> 2.) Add a .pth file to the directory $HOME/path/to/anaconda/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages. This can be named
>   anything (it just must end with .pth). A .pth file is just a
>   newline-separated listing of the full path-names of directories that
>   will be added to your path on Python startup.
>
> Both work straightforward and I went for the second option as it is
>   more flexible.
>
> *** UPDATE:
>
> 3.) Create a setup.py in the folder of your package and install it using pip install -e /path/to/package which is the cleanest option
>   from my point of view because you can also see all installations using
>   pip list.
>
> Thanks anyway!

Comment: Added to answer above.

Comment: Thanks TD-Asker.
When I'm using the third option I get this message:
"No files/directories in C:\rnd\ErezLaxBranch\python\GeometricUtils (from PKG-INFO)"
Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Please report back what option was best and I can highlight this in my answer here for future visitors.

Comment: Hi again,Thanks for your help.
I'm trying now all the options and have no success..
My case is that I have 2 folders with .py files inside, some of the files in the folders import functions from other etc.
How can I include these two folders with all their files in the path?

Comment: You just need to add both folders to your system path. #1 or #3 should work if you do it for each folder.

Answer (score 3):

look, on python 2.7 it will be work, but on python 3 you get some errors...

if you write some functions in other file, you need import this file. if this file in the same folder - it is good. but if in sub folder... in sub folder you need create empty file **init**.py
and now, if you will try import your module from sub file - also will be work

**impotent (for python 3)**:
use this code

```js
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '/modules')
import my_module
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of my answer? Can you point out what's different?

Comment: different in that, you use constant path_to_file, i use dynamic path_to_file. i know that i use sub folder and i do not know were on PC my program be. your variant is also good. and can help if know path_to_file on PC

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't already, try using the full pathname of the function in your code.

```
from Folder1.Folder2.FileName import ModuleName

someVar = ModuleName(params)
```

`Folder1` would be a folder in the same directory as your main program.
Also, create an empty file called `__init__.py` in every folder you import from.

Comment: OK. thanks. it helps a bit.
But there any way to add specific path as permanent module?
Like as I add new package to anaconda?

Comment: TD-Asker's answer might be the solution to that.

Comment: It worked  a bit ago, Now it doesn't. Jupyter can get confused, so in that case I had to restart the workbook